# Adding a grid on top of a tif image in python

Tags: matplotlib

Hi I was wondering how to add a grid on top of my image then display it in python.
Here is a picture of what I want to do.  NOTE: I also want to specify the line type and color for some of the blocks in the image just like the image below.
Thanks a lot.
[image: this image was generated in matlab]

Answer (score 1):

The example below shows how to display a .tif file, create a grid, but also how to put the grid below the other plot elements so that you can draw boxes and lines on top of the image and the grid.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

im = Image.open('stinkbug.tif')

# Flip the .tif file so it plots upright
im1 = im.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)

# Plot the image
plt.imshow(im1)
ax = plt.gca()

# create a grid
ax.grid(True, color='r', linestyle='--', linewidth=2)
# put the grid below other plot elements
ax.set_axisbelow(True)

# Draw a box
xy = 200, 200,
width, height = 100, 100
ax.add_patch(mpatches.Rectangle(xy, width, height, facecolor="none",
    edgecolor="blue", linewidth=2))

plt.draw()

plt.show()
```

You can use matplotlib.patches to draw all types of shapes over your image. To draw individual lines, I like to use the following line, but you can also use matplotlib.lines.Line2D.

```
plt.axvline(x=0.069, ymin=0, ymax=40, linewidth=4, color='r')
```

Answer (score 0):

There's `imshow` function for displaying the image. Displaying the grid on top of the axes is as simple as `grid(True).`